# PHP Async GET request works on one server, but doesn't on the other

Tags: php, asynchronous, get

**Please see the edits at the bottom for additional information!**

I have two servers. Both should be able to call each other with a GET request.
To make the request (it's more firing an event than makeing a request actually) I am using this code:

```
function URLCallAsync($url, $params, $type='POST')
{
      foreach ($params as $key => &$val) {
        if (is_array($val)) $val = implode(',', $val);
        $post_params[] = $key.'='.urlencode($val);
      }
  $post_string = implode('&', $post_params);

  $parts=parse_url($url);

  $fp = fsockopen($parts['host'],
      isset($parts['port'])?$parts['port']:80,
      $errno, $errstr, 30);

  // Data goes in the path for a GET request
  if('GET' == $type) $parts['path'] .= '?'.$post_string;

  $out = "$type ".$parts['path']." HTTP/1.1\r\n";
  $out.= "Host: ".$parts['host']."\r\n";
  $out.= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
  $out.= "Content-Length: ".strlen($post_string)."\r\n";
  $out.= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";
  // Data goes in the request body for a POST request
  if ('POST' == $type && isset($post_string)) $out.= $post_string;

  fwrite($fp, $out);
  fclose($fp);
}
```

I feed the function with the exact same data (but the url) on both servers (I copied the calling file to test it!!) but it only works in one direction!

I write the calls to that function in a log file so I can investigate if something is going wrong.

Server A -> Server B, works exactly as it should, the logfile at server A contains the correct url

Server B -> Server A, only prints the correct information in the logfile of server B, but Server A never receives the request.

What could be the reason for something like this?

edit:
Could it be the differnt kinds of server?
Server A is nginx, Server B is apache.
Server A also has a '~' symbol in it's url, maybe thats the problem?
The parameters of the get request are encoded with php's "urlencode" maybe that creates problems?

I tried around a bit, but the problem is still that the request isn't coming trough to Server A. But from a browser it works perfectly somehow (assuming I enter the correct URL with the parameters).

edit2:
If I exchange "URLCallAsync" with "file_get_contents" it works like it should. But the problem is that file_get_contents is blocking!
So it can only be the function itself. But strangely it works in the opposite direction :(

edit3:
The function "URLCallAsync" runs trough without error, notice or anything else.
It just isn't received by the other server.
What exactly is file_get_contents doing so different???

Answer (score 0):

I got it working.

After a lot of fiddling with wireshark I found that file_get_contents is even simpler than my async function!

It simply omits the Content-Length field completly! It just provides "GET ..." and "Host".
It also uses HTTP/1.0 instead of 1.1, but that didn't change anything.

So the solution is: Also posting the Content-Length header (which had the value 0, since i used GET) will somehow make the server reject the request. I don't know for sure if it was the server that rejected the request, or something else, like a firewall that maybe detected a "malformed" request, but at least the problem is solved.

So next time you send requests, don't provide the Content-Length header if you don't need it :)